# RangeError: Invalid array length when printing a heatmap in Grafana

Tags: grafana, heatmap

Well,

For some reason I have a Kusto query (which I'll not share) that generates over ~500 rows and ~40 columns.

Then, I don't know why, but the following error is printed: `RangeError: Invalid array length` when I try to visualize the data on a heatmap visualization.

I'm looking for the limits of this visualization on Internet and I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to filter out null (NaN) values.
In my case it was the same error `RangeError: Invalid array length` for :

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(search_duration_bucket[5m])) by (le))
```

I have added  `> 0` to query and its works

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(search_duration_bucket[5m])) by (le) > 0)
```